# Azure API management custom domain root page

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We are setting up Azure API management for our APIs with a custom domain. We have APIs under seperate paths e.g.

1. https://api.company.com/api1
2. https://api.company.com/api2

etc.

If we goto https://api.company.com/ we get:

```
{
"statusCode": 404,
"message": "Resource not found"
}
```

If we wanted to create just a message here e.g.

```
{
"name": "Company API"
}
```

What is the easiest way to do this? Can we have a global policy to handle this or do we have to create a new API with some kind of mock response?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an api with no api suffix and Get operation under it with / as a URI template.